# Suppressing log output from cypress commands

Tags: javascript, cypress

below is the code i am using to validate that download made it to the downloads folder.
The file is of csv format. filepath is declared at the top.

the test passes but the command log outputs the entire content from the file for both the assertions(should and contains). how do i suppress the command log from outputting the entire body from the file. i already tried passing the false flag and it still outputs everything.
using cypress version 9.2

```
it('verify download',() => {   
  // some code here to fill in the form data and initiate download
  cy.readFile(filepath,{
    log : false
  }).should('exist').and('contains',"some text to assert")
})
```

Comment: Sounds like something to reduce to [mcve] so you can report a bug on the [Cypress issue tracker](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues) (after search the open issues first of course)?

Comment: Yes, i did skim through github and found this . i was wondering if i could find an alternate solution 
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7693

Comment: Remember to include all details [in your post](/help/how-to-ask). That includes talking about what you already found/tried.